# iframe reloading after screen resize

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe that loads the content and dynamically resizes itself after the content has loaded, to match the height of the content.  I'm using this code to to resize the iframe, it's located in the document ready section

```
var frame = $('#formFrame', window.parent.document);
var height = $('#main').height();
frame.height(height + 40);
frame.width("720");
```

My problem is that the iframe seems to be reloading any time the window is resized, which of course is clearing out any form data that was entered into the form.  I'm not using any jquery that checks for the browser window being resized, nor am I running any jquery that refreshes the internal page.  So I'm not exactly sure if this is an iframe issue or a jquery issue.  My iframe looks like this...

```
<iframe id="formFrame" width="720" height="240" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://www.ncat.edu/caes/comm-form-system/index.html"></iframe>
```

I'm applying no CSS to the iframe below is the CSS to my main division that the jquery is using to base the size of the iframe off of.

```
.main-div {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 5px;

}
```

Comment: Is the Javascript code in a function or just simply by itself in a <script> tag?

Comment: It's housed with in $(document).ready(function(){...});